# Partials in handlebar templates with slashes cause error

Tags: handlebars.js

I am using the runtime build of handlebars and trying to use a registered partial. I do:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial("path/partialname", Handlebars.templates["path/partialname"])
```

If I use a slash in a partial name like so:

```
{{> path/partialname}}
```

I get the error

```
The partial path.partialname could not be found [...]/lib/handlebars/handlebars.runtime
```

The "/" seems to be substituted for a "."

How can I use a "/" inside the partial without modifying the Handlebars.registerPartial call? Thx alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution I put together:

```
// automaticly register all templates as partials, so we dont have to do it manually
// https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/190
// also convert slashes to dots in the template name because this is how
// handlebars resolves partial names.
 _.each(Handlebars.templates, function(val, key){
    var key = key.replace(/\//g, ".")
    Handlebars.partials[key] = val
})
```